# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{3a} \frac{x\sqrt{3a-x}}{\sqrt{a+x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How can we evaluate following integral:

$$I=\int_{0}^{3a} \frac{x\sqrt{3a-x}}{\sqrt{a+x}} dx$$

I tried using the property $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx$ but it not helping because of the denominator. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a>0$. One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{3a} \frac{x\sqrt{3a-x}}{\sqrt{a+x}} dx &=a^2\int_{0}^{3} \frac{t\sqrt{3-t}}{\sqrt{1+t}} dt \qquad (x=at)
\\\\&=2a^2\int_{1}^{2} (u^2-1)\sqrt{4-u^2}\: du \qquad \left(u=\sqrt{1+t}\:\right)
\\\\&=8a^2\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} (3-4\cos^2 v)\cos^2 v\: dv \qquad \left(u=2\sin v\:\right)
\\\\&=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}2 a^2,
\end{align}
$$ where we have used 
$$
\cos^2 v=\frac{1+\cos(2v)}2
$$ twice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This is classic. Use substitution:
 $$t=\sqrt{\dfrac{3a-x}{a+x}}\iff x=a\frac{3-t^2}{t^2+1},\enspace t\ge 0$$

Comment: You mean $t=\cdots$  right?

Comment: Oh! Yes. Thanks for pointing it. It's corrected now.

Comment: Welcome. Nice rationalization.

Comment: I've learnt it as standard (rational function of $x$ and the square root of a homographic function). Your method is faster in the present case, though.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As we need $3a\ge x>-a\iff2a\ge x-a>-2a,$

let $x-a=2a\cos2t$

WLOG, $0\le2t\le\pi\iff0\le t\le\dfrac\pi2$

$$\dfrac{3a-x}{a+x}=\tan^2t\implies\sqrt{\dfrac{3a-x}{a+x}}=+\tan t$$

Can you take it from here?